# Вопрос по unit-тестам на С# по NUnit. Непонятна логика тестов

Tags: c#

В тестировании совсем еще новичок. Не совсем понятна логика работы  с boolen значениями.Вот промежуток кода, к нему нужно написать тесты. Как мне показалось нужно писать здесь их через false и true. Может быть кто-то может на примере показать данного кода?

```
    public static bool IsDigitOnly(string text)
    {
        foreach (char t in text)
        {
            if (t < '0' || t > '9')
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Вы ввели не цифры, как мы будем их складывать?");
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: public static bool IsDigitOnly(string text)
почему-то не вставилось перед foreach

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Я Вам без всяких тестов скажу, что код плохой. Функция проверяет строку, содержит ли та только цифры. Никакого вывода в консоль там быть не должно. Откуда функция знает о "складывании" цифр?

Comment: Возможно код правда плохой, его составляла не я, вопрос заключается в другом :)
Окей, попытаюсь перефразировать. К данному промежутку кода мне нужно написать юнит-тесты через Assert.True и Assert.False. Просто какие я значения я не вставляю, тесты не запускаются